# finding index of vowels in a string clojure

Tags: clojure

Hi am learning clojure and trying to find the index of the vowels in a string here is what I tried

```clj
(def vowels [\a \e \i \o \u \y])
(let [word-index (interleave "aaded" (range))
      indexs (for [ [x i] (vector word-index)
                   :when (some #{x} vowels)]
               [i] )]
  (seq indexs))
```

But this is giving me index "0" or nill what am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to form the input correctly for the for comprehension:

```clj
(let [word-index (interleave "aaded" (range))
      indexs (for [[x i] (partition 2 word-index)
                   :when (some #{x} vowels)]
               i)]
  (prn (seq indexs)))

;; => (0 1 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
> (def vowels #{\a \e \i \o \u})

> (filter some? (map #(when (vowels %1) %2) "aaded" (range)))
(0 1 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

interleave will give a lazy sequence when we mapped that sequence to the vector of for loop, I think I missed the indexes. So changed the implementation as below.

```
(let [word-index (zipmap (range) "aaded")
      indexs (for [ [i x]  word-index
                   :when (some #{x}  vowels)]
                   [i] )
      ]
   (flatten indexs)
  )
```

Which is working fine, if anyone has better implementation please share. It will be helpful for me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With every iteration of the for function, the same hash-set is formed repeatedly. So it's better to define it in the `let` block. Also, we can use the `hash-set` directly as a function and we don't need the `some` function for the same.

```
(let [word-index (zipmap (range) "aaded")
      vowels-hash (into #{} [\a \e \i \o \u \y])
      indexs (for [[i x]  word-index
                   :when (vowels-hash x)]
               [i])]
  (flatten indexs))
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit different approach with regex:

for all indices:

```
user> (let [m (re-matcher #"[aeiou]" "banedif")]
        (take-while identity (repeatedly #(when (re-find m) (.start m)))))
;;=> (1 3 5)
```

for single index:

```
user> (let [m (re-matcher #"[aeiou]" "bfsendf")]
        (when (re-find m) (.start m)))
;;=> 3

user> (let [m (re-matcher #"[aeiou]" "bndf")]
        (when (re-find m) (.start m)))
;;=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

@jas has got this nailed down already. Adding my own to provide some comments on what happens in intermediary steps.

Use sets to check for membership. Then the question "is this a vowel?" will be fast.

```clj
(def vowels (set "aeiouy"))
vowels
;; => #{\a \e \i \o \u \y}
```

We can filter out the vowels, then get just the indexes

```clj
(defn vowel-indices-1 [word]
  (->> (map vector (range) word)      ; ([0 \h] [1 \e] [2 \l] ...)
       (filter (fn [[_ character]]    ; ([1 \e] [4 \o])
                 (contains? vowels character)))
       (map first)))                  ; (1 4)

(vowel-indices-1 "hello!")
;; => (1 4)
```

... or we can go for a slightly more fancy with the :when keyword (didn't know about that, thanks!), in the style that you started!

```clj
(defn vowel-indices-2 [word]
  (for [[i ch] (map vector (range) word)
        :when (contains? vowels ch)]
    i))

(vowel-indices-2 "hello!")
;; => (1 4)
```